# how to make EVT_TEXT_ENTER work with EVT_KILL_FOCUS?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a text ctrl where user gives number.
once he finished i want to perform an operation.

I know the user finished when the textctrl loses focus or when he press enter.

I did the following:

```
        self.a= wx.TextCtrl(self, -1,style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER) 
        self.a.Bind(wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS, self.OnA)
        self.a.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.OnA)

    def onA(self,event):
        print "hello"
        event.Skip()
```

My problem is that if the users click somewhere else with the mouse then eveything works. hello is printed once which means that `EVT_KILL_FOCUS` happened.
but if uses press enter than hello is printed twice. It means that both `EVT_KILL_FOCUS` and `EVT_TEXT_ENTER` happed. I don't want to proccess the event twice.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is not to code for both events.
I would choose EVT_KILL_FOCUS and forget about EVT_TEXT_ENTER and remember to remove the `event.Skip()`
Edit:
Your problem is that you are mixing a wx.Event (kill-focus) and a wx.commandevent (enter) see: http://wiki.wxpython.org/EventPropagation for further information. The issue here,I think, is that wx.commandevent (Enter) is causing the kill-focus event.
Edit 2:
Assign the events to different functions.
In the function that is used for the `EVT_TEXT_ENTER` unbind the `EVT_KILL_FOCUS`, output your error message and then re-bind the `EVT_KILL_FOCUS` event
i.e.

```
self.a.Unbind(wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS)
(do whatever to announce that there is a error here)
self.a.Bind(wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS, self.OnA)
```

Comment: It's not my decision... it's Client request. Why to remove event.Skip()?

Comment: `event.Skip()` tells it to continue processing events other than this one, that is the last thing that you require, in this case.

Comment: Does it apply only for events that are handled in the same functions or all events in general? say I also have self.a.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.OnB)

Comment: Try self.a.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT,self.OnB) and self.a.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN,self.OnC) and see the difference with and without the event.Skip(). It's an eye opener ;)